# Главная страница не открывается на корневой папке ( HTDOCS )

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

Я создал веб-сайт на Joomla, мультиязычный.
Я изменил в файле `.htaccess` код для rewrite, чтобы открывался без index.php.

Проблема в том, что сайт не открывается на корневой папке HTDOCS.

Когда я открываю сайт и пишу в адресной строке `localhost`, он перенаправляется по адресу `localhost/tm/`. Сайт пуст, выводится только символ `>`

Когда я переместил сайт в подпапку, он стал открывать `localhost/A/tm/`. Страница открывается без ошибок.

Как мне отредактировать файл `.htaccess`, чтобы открыть сайт в корневой папке?

Вот содержимое `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```